# Opening specific posts on WP takes lot of time and freezes the editor

Tags: wp-admin, performance

I have this weird problem in the last couple of days where it takes ~5 minutes to completely open some posts on WordPress wp-admin dashboard.

Please hear me out carefully.

1. This is happening only with 1 person in the team. Not an issue for others in the team (same role, same posts)
2. I have tried different browsers, different machines. I even shared my credentials with my editor and he faced the exact same issue.
3. We have disabled Gutenberg and using classic editor. No issues while using Gutenberg (but that's not really an option). The page freezes for approx 5 minutes on opening and eventually loads completely.
4. It's mostly happening for "some" of my own posts already published (it's a multi-authored blog), but I can't be 100% sure since it's all so random.

Here's what all we have tried till now;

1. Tried using Query monitor. Nothing untoward found.
2. Tried activating redis cache. Didn't help.
3. Tried changing my role from Editor to Admin. Didn't help.
4. Deactivated 5-6 recently installed plugins. No luck.

In response to queries, here’s what I see-

Attached below are two screenshots: first image is what appears in the Network tab on Chrome. Second is what the editor sees on the console.
￼
￼[image: what appears in the Network tab on Chrome]

[image: what the editor sees in the console]

Comment: I don't think there's much we can do about this, sorry, except suggest things for you to try. If it's that long I'd guess something is trying to make a connection that times out either in your browser or on the server, so it's probably worth trying to work out which end is freezing. You could e.g. look at the network tab in your browser tools to see what if any connections are open for those five minutes.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if Media Library or a plugin is attempting to load lots of thumbnails for uploaded images, which are either 404'ing or otherwise not loading? I've noticed a couple instances where runaway failed attempts at loading Media Library thumbs can hang a browser. Check browser extensions, too - it sounds like it could be a blocked script, that is continuously retrying some action.

Comment: @Rup I’ve added two screenshots of what I see in the network tab and what the editor sees on the console.

Comment: @wrydere Also, side note, the problem is noticed on a different computer as well. So, it’s very likely that there’s something wrong on the WP side.

Comment: I didn't mean the browser was freezing on its own, but getting stuck doing something one of the scripts on the page was telling it to do. So that wouldn't be specific to one computer, no.

Comment: Can you deduce something from those screenshots?

Comment: Both that admin-ajax and wp-cron call look wrong though. Can you look at the admin-ajax request and see what the action is? I guess it's been POSTed so you'll have to look at the request details. And your browser shouldn't be calling wp-cron - can you find out what's triggering that?

Comment: What do you suggest would be the best way to find that out?

Comment: [This post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajax-php_fs_blog_admintrue/) says that the _fs_blog_admin part is added by Freemius, which is a framework for paid-for plugins and themes, so that might be a place to start. But if you look at that request in your browser debug tools, click on it and look at the 'Headers' tab or similar you should see a request body with an 'action' parameter. Once you know what that string is, search your whole WordPress installation for that string. Or it might be obvious where it comes from from the name.

Comment: Sorry, but I only see ‘action’ under ‘Form Data’.

Comment: Great, yes, that will be the one. What is it, and can you find what's generating the call to it?

Comment: I don’t see anything specific under Form Data. The value for action is ‘get_post_suggestions’ and for type it is ‘outbound_suggestions’.  Clicking on ‘view source’ next to Form Data shows ‘action’ with a pretty lengthy value.

Comment: @Rup anything you feel could help in this situation? The problem is now prevalent on newer posts as well, making things all the way more difficult to worth with.

Comment: It sounds like it’s the related post suggestions system. Maybe the affected posts are too similar to lots of other posts and so it’s hard to compute the best matches. What do you use for that? Can you try turning that off temporarily?

Comment: However that wouldn’t explain the cron request though, unless the related posts function somehow triggers a cron job because it needs to recompute related posts?

Comment: Bu, why would that only affect one user? Other users are not encountering any such issues.

Comment: I’ve highlighted it in the question, but to reiterate, the problem is happening on just one WP profile. No other user is experiencing it. Also, the profile that’s causing the problem is not specific to one computer. Even the editor notices those issues when he logs in to that profile at his place on his machine.

Comment: The editor created a new profile as a workaround. But the issue appears on the new profile as well. What could be wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: @Rup any suggestion?

Comment: No, sorry. I still think it's worth working out exactly what's happening when it's slow, and I still think it's worth looking at those two pending requests in your network tab, which you said was the post suggestions.